Second Law Caveats
The second law says that the entropy of an isolated system always increases, however it does not say much about the manner in which it should.
Suppose we have a system comprised of two subsystems and entropy suddenly decreases someplace in the first and increases somewhere in the second. Does there need to be a "path of influence" between these two regions? i.e A connected path where energy exchange is given between the two portions? Or is it sufficient for the two portions to be mysteriously correlated in their entropy production rates?

What you are asking is out of the scope of second law of thermodynamics. It just states that entropy increases globally  in a closed system. It does not say anything (and does not have to) about local entropy changes or entropy correlations between different system parts. One probable reason may be that these local entropy changes can go either way and it's not in the scope of this law.

So then it is sufficient for entropy production to just be correlated?

If you can determine the final equilibrium state of the combined system using the 1st law of thermodynamics when the impediment to equilibration ins removed, then you can determine the entropy change, and it will be positive.

If there is no connection between the systems then presumably I can consider only the system where the entropy decrease occurs and apply the second law to this system. If the combined system is isolated and there is no connection between the systems then this system is isolated and the second law to conclude that the decrease cannot occur. Now if the systems are connected things are more complicated. The change in entropy should be accompanied by an exchange of work or heat. I suspect you would have to refine the idea of a "path of influence" to make further progress


Suppose we have a system comprised of two subsystems ... Does there need to be a "path of influence" between these two regions ?

If we are going to apply the second law of thermodynamics to each separate subsystem then the two subsystems must be isolated i.e. there is no connection of any kind between them. On the other hand, if the subsystems are connected then the second law of thermodynamics will not apply to each individual subsystem, but only (possibly) to the system as a whole.

Is it sufficient for the two portions to be mysteriously correlated in their entropy production rates ?

Sufficient for what ? It is certainly possible for the entropy of two unconnected systems to be correlated, in the same way as it is possible for you and I, located in two different cities, to toss a coin and produce identical sequences of heads and tails. However, the longer this correlation continues, the more likely it is that there is some as yet undetected connection between the systems. If you and I throw identical sequences of five heads/tails this could easily be coincidence; if you and I throw identical sequences of five hundred heads/tails then coincidence is less likely.


Does there need to be a "path of influence" between these two regions?
i.e A connected path where energy exchange is given between the two
portions?

If by "connected path" you mean a well defined process, the answer is no.
The entropy of the isolated system can only increase or remain the same. It will remain the same if the system is in equilibrium internally without the need for internal constraints. It will increase if the removal of internal constraints results in disequilibrium.
However, as @Chet Miller pointed out, the lack of a "connected path" does not preclude calculation of the increase in entropy as long as you can determine the final equilibrium state of the combined sub-systems using the first law of thermodynamics, with the knowledge that there can be no change in internal energy for an isolated system. The entropy change can then be calculated by devising any convenient reversible "connected path" between the initial and final states and applying the following definition of entropy change:
$$\Delta S_{12}=\int_1^2\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$$
Note that since entropy is a state function, the chosen path need not have anything to do with the actual process and thus need not be limited to an isolated system. For a description of the steps involved I recommend the following by @Chet Miller: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/
Hope this helps.

There are thermodynamic professionals (physicists and engineers) of whom Truesdell in his book Rational Thermodynamics, 1984, pp.79-80, wrote the following longish but quite interesting comment discussing the concept of nonequilibrium entropy.

For the slightly disequilibrated professional I will make only two remarks
in passing. First, in mechanics the concept of force originated in
statics and was carried over bodily, if with much delay and discussion, to
motions. If the restoring force exerted by a spring is proportional to the
increase of its length in a static experiment, will it still be so when a ball
is attached to the end and set into oscillation, especially if the experiment
is performed in a spaceship in orbit around the moon? Indeed, does it
make sense to talk about forces at all in a moving system? The forces, it
seems, might be affected by the motions, yet we are supposed to know the
forces first in order to determine what the motion will be. These questions,
and far subtler ones of the same kind, were asked in the seventeenth
century; today the freshman is trained specifically not to ask them.
Perhaps he ought to; but if he does, he is more likely to take up philosophy
than science; and if NEWTON had insisted that forces be used only
when they can be measured by an operationalist who works and thinks
very, very slowly, it is unlikely anyone would be designing spaceships today.
The professionals who moan that temperature is a concept for equilibrium
alone are not solving any problems themselves; they are merely
pronouncing our problems insoluble and sneering at us for trying to solve
them.
Second, the professional theorists of thermodynamics show a lack of
respect for experiment I find hard to admire. Experiments are being
done today in all sorts of extreme conditions. My friends and colleagues tell me
they measure the temperatures in polymer solutions undergoing strong
normal-stress effects, they control the temperatures in explosion fronts,
they infer the temperatures on the skins of artificial satellites. It would be
presumptuous on my part to question the details of the work of these
men, and I see no reason to deny that they know their business. The temperatures
occurring as values of the temperature function $\theta(\cdot)$ in modern
theories of materials are intended to represent the numbers these experimenters
report and call "temperatures", although their systems bear little
likeness to those the old books on thermodynamics describe as being "in
equilibrium ", and their processes seem to have little in common with
whatever it is the thermodynamicists mean by "quasi-static". I do not
claim that we yet know whether or not a particular theory be borne out
by any particular experiment, but I do not see why the professionals
should forbid us from trying to explain the experiments by a rational
theory, approached in that very spirit everyone today regards as the right
one for mechanics and electromagnetism.

What surprises me is not that the common view, which Truesdell rather trenchantly criticizes in the quote above, habitually rejects entropy unless defined along a reversible path but that the same people who do so have no problem with the concepts of internal energy, transported heat, temperature, etc. in most irreversible processes. I am yet to hear a cogent argument, not personal preference, that under the circumstances when absolute temperature, internal energy, and various work processes and their mechanical and other macroscopic variables are meaningfully definable, so we are not talking about a dozen molecules interacting and some such, and also "heat" at any given locale is defined then why the ratio of that same "heat" divided by the absolute temperature at that locale cannot be called the entropy and be consistent with the same equilibrium quantity when defined by a hypothetical reversible process. In the same work Truesdell semi-joked that to avoid the arguments over whether one may call the ratio $q/T$ "entropy", we should just go with Carnot and call it "calorique" and be done with the debate$^*$.
And here is another quote expressing very nicely the same idea in Steinour: "Heat and  Entropy", 1948:

As already shown, heat-in-transfer must be regarded
as TS energy if entropy is thought of as being transferred
from one system to another instead of being destroyed
and reproduced. Conversely, identification of
heat with TS energy leads naturally to the thought that
entropy does undergo transfer, like mass and electric
charge. If entropy is regarded as randomness or disorder,
this mobile quality should not seem strange.
Anything done to reduce the randomness at one place
can simply he regarded as moving the disorder elsewhere,
often with production of additional disorder
hut never with any decrease. This mobility is a property
to he valued since it enables entropy to he regarded
as indestructible. Thus, it increases the tangibility
of the entropy concept.
Indeed, it seems strange that entropy transfer is not generally
recognized as the common-sense view. Entropy (of system plus
surroundings) remains constant in reversible processes and can only
increase in irreversible ones. This increase represents a creation of
new entropy under well-understood conditions which imply in no way the
concurrent destruction of any preexisting entropy. Thus, the entropy
existing at any one time can be regarded as something that is
thereafter conserved, i. e., that always remains the same number of
units. Furthermore, entropy can be traced along continuous paths in
its redistributions. Other entities, such as gravitational mass or
electrical charge, that exhibit such properties are not thought of as
being destroyed and re-created but as moving about. There appears to
be every reason to regard an entropy unit in the same way. When we do
so, we find that we have something strikingly analogous - an
indestructible entity that moves under a potential difference, and
that always has associated with it potential energy proportional to
its potential level, or temperature.


$^*$ Carnot's calorique is 200 years old this year.
